# Why is this operator independent of the choice of basis

Tags: rt.representation-theory, linear-algebra, lie-groups, lie-algebras, tensor-products

I asked this question in MSE but I received no answer

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4009524/why-is-the-following-operator-independent-of-the-choice-of-basis/4013636#4013636
Let $G$ be a lie group with lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$ and let $M$ be a $G$-manifold. We denote the space of smooth differential forms on $M$ by $A(M)$. Let $E^i$ be a basis of $\mathfrak{g}$ and let $E_i$ $\in \mathfrak{g}^*$ be the dual basis. Let $S(\mathfrak{g}^*)$ be the symmetric algebra of $\mathfrak{g}^*$. Define the operator $\overline{d}$ on $S(\mathfrak{g}^*) \otimes A(M)$ by

$$\overline{d}(P \otimes \alpha)= \sum_i E_iP \otimes \iota (E^i_M) \alpha$$

for $P \in S(\mathfrak{g}^*)$ and $\alpha \in A(M)$ (note that $\iota (E^i_M)$ is the contraction by the vector field $E^i_M$ wich is defined by $$(E^i_M.f)(m)= \frac{d}{dt} \bigg|_{t=0} f(\exp(tE^i)m),$$ for $f \in C^\infty(M)$ and $m \in M$).

My question is why  the definition of $\overline{d}$ is independent of the choice of the basis $E^i$ ?

Actually, I get this question by reading section $2$ of the article of equivariant cohomology with generalized coefficients by Kumar and Vergne, and the authors have commented on this by saying the following

> This expression is independent of the choice of the basis $E^i$, as the element $\sum_i E_i \otimes E^i \in \mathfrak{g}^* \otimes \mathfrak{g}$ is the canonical element $I \in \operatorname{End}(\mathfrak{g})$, where $I$ is the identity element of $\operatorname{End}(\mathfrak{g})$.

But I didn't understand their comment! Moreover, I tried to prove this independence in the case where $\mathfrak{g}$ is one dimensional without going any where.

Please help with this.

Comment: The key thing to note is that the map $(X \mapsto X_M) : \mathfrak{g} \to \mathfrak{X}(M)$ is actually $\mathbb{R}$-linear, so all the usual elementary linear algebra that tells you that $\sum_i E_i \otimes E^i = \sum_i \tilde{E}_i \otimes \tilde{E}^i$ for any two bases $\{E^i\}$ and $\{\tilde{E}^i\}$ for $\mathfrak{g}$ will still apply.

Comment: @Branimir, thank you so much for your comment, could you please tell me where I can find it because this is the first time I see it

Comment: Thanks for mentioning that you asked the question already on math.stackexchange. When you do this in the future, could you please make sure to edit each question to include a link to the other? That way if someone makes progress on one, people can easily see it before working on the other.

Comment: @Will Sawin, thank you for your remark, I'll add the link of my question in MSE.